# Go maps and slices with mixed struct types

Tags: inheritance, go, data-structures, struct, interface

I'm trying to learn how to work with Go by creating a simple event store with the ability to create projections. I get stuck on how to work with slices and maps that contains structs of mixed types. The point with this would be that I want a developer to create as many structs implementing IEntity and IEvent as needed with various fields.

I come from a JavaScript/Node.js background with some basic knowledge of C/C++/Java and I'm probably looking to much for class/inheritance patterns here and need some help on how to get the same functionality in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"

    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

// IEntity describes an entity, a struct that is the sum of all events resolved in a chronological order
type IEntity interface {
}

// IProjection describes the interface for a projection struct
type IProjection interface {
    Lock()
    Unlock()
    Get(id uuid.UUID) IEntity
    Set(id uuid.UUID, entity IEntity)
    GetLastEventTime() time.Time
    Append(event IEvent)
}

// IEvent describes the interface for a event, any event added to the system needs to implement this interface
type IEvent interface {
    Resolve(projection IProjection)
}

// EventVault is the base struct that keeps all the events and allows for projections to be created
type EventVault struct {
    sync.Mutex
    events []IEvent
}

// Append adds a IEvent to the projection and runs that events IEvent.Resolve method
func (vault *EventVault) Append(event IEvent) {
    vault.Lock()
    defer vault.Unlock()
    vault.events = append(vault.events, event)
}

// Project creates a projection with entities from all events up until the choosen end time
func (vault *EventVault) Project(endTime time.Time, projection IProjection) IProjection {
    lastEventTime := projection.GetLastEventTime()
    for index := range vault.events {
        event := vault.events[index]
        if event.Time.After(lastEventTime) && event.Time.Before(endTime) {
            projection.Append(event)
        }
    }
    return projection
}

// Projection caculates and stores a projection of the events appended to it with the Append method
type Projection struct {
    sync.Mutex
    events   []IEvent
    entities map[uuid.UUID]IEntity
}

// Get returns an IEntity struct from an id (for use in the IEvent.Resolve method)
func (projection *Projection) Get(id uuid.UUID) IEntity {
    return projection.entities[id]
}

// Set add a IEntity to the projection (for use in the IEvent.Resolve method)
func (projection *Projection) Set(id uuid.UUID, entity IEntity) {
    projection.entities[id] = entity
}

// GetLastEventTime returns the time for the event that was added last
func (projection *Projection) GetLastEventTime() time.Time {
    event := projection.events[len(projection.events)-1]

    if event == nil {
        return time.Unix(0, 0)
    }

    return event.Time
}

// Append adds a IEvent to the projection and runs that events IEvent.Resolve method
func (projection *Projection) Append(event IEvent) {
    projection.Lock()
    projection.events = append(projection.events, event)
    event.Resolve(projection)
    projection.Unlock()
}

// ------------------ Below is usage of above system ------------------

// PlayerEntity is a sample entity that can be used for testing
type PlayerEntity struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID
    Name      string
    Birthday  time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

// AddPlayerEvent is a sample event that can be used for testing
type AddPlayerEvent struct {
    ID   uuid.UUID
    Time time.Time
    Name string
}

// Resolve will create a new PlayerEntity and add that to the projection
func (event *AddPlayerEvent) Resolve(projection IProjection) {
    player := PlayerEntity{ID: uuid.NewV4(), Name: event.Name, UpdatedAt: event.Time}
    projection.Set(player.ID, &player)
}

// SetBirthdayPlayerEvent is a sample event that can be used for testing
type SetBirthdayPlayerEvent struct {
    ID       uuid.UUID
    Time     time.Time
    Birthday time.Time
}

// Resolve will change the name on a PlayerEntity
func (event *SetBirthdayPlayerEvent) Resolve(projection IProjection) {
    player := *projection.Get(event.ID)
    player.Birthday = event.Birthday
    player.UpdatedAt = event.Time
}

func main() {
    vault := EventVault{}
    event1 := AddPlayerEvent{ID: uuid.NewV4(), Time: time.Now(), Name: "Lisa"}
    vault.Append(&event1)
    birthday, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2017-03-04")
    event2 := SetBirthdayPlayerEvent{ID: event1.ID, Time: time.Now(), Birthday: birthday}
    vault.Append(&event2)
}
```

The errors I get are

```
./main.go:47: event.Time undefined (type IEvent has no field or method Time)
./main.go:79: event.Time undefined (type IEvent has no field or method Time)
./main.go:122: invalid indirect of projection.Get(event.ID) (type IEntity)
```

The struct types are probably lost so I need another way of storing them to put them into the maps and slices but how?

Comment: Are we supposed to run our fingers down the screen until we count 122 lines, or would you like to point out where the problem is? :)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can probably add `Time() time.Time` to your `IEvent` interface. Furthermore, you need to implement a method called `Time() time.Time` to your structs and update the given lines 47,79 to `event.Time()`.

Comment: Yes but I see two problems with this, one that I would have to add a getter/setter for all properties, two that if I add an entity e.g. called TreeEntity with properties Kind string, Branches []Branch and so on they would have different getters/setters because of having different properties so that would break in the Resolve methods. :/

I'm so used to loosely types languages :/

Answer (score 1):

In golang when you declare an interface like

```
type IEntity interface {
}
```

You define everything that can be done with this interface without a type cast. So here you have defined no functionality for this interface. If you want functionality than you have to give it a method like

```
type IEntity interface {
    Time() time.Time
}
```

Any type that wants to be used with that interface must implement those functions i.e.

```
func (a AddPlayerEvent) Time() time.Time {
    return a.Time 
}
```

[See the docs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types)

Then you can use any of those methods

```
func (projection *Projection) Append(event IEvent) {
    ...
    event.Time()
    ...
}
```

2 more notes

- When iterating through a map you can use k, v := range my_map
- *projection.Get(event.ID)  attempts to deference a non pointer type

Comment: So the answer would be that I have to use getters/setters for all properties added to a struct, that is not exactly the answer I was hoping for but maybe it's the only way. Would have been so nice if there was another way of saving references in slice/map to a mix of structs without the need for getter/setter, even if the interface was not needed would be nice.

I did try with getters/setters without success but I guess I need to practice some more to get my head around this. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Right, to be clear you don't have to use an interface as the type you are passing to the method/store in the struct, but if you are going to use an interface the interface better have all the methods you need.

Comment: Changing player.Birthday to a setter requires me to add SetBirthday(time time.Time) to the IEntity which since not all entities will have to property Birthday breaks the complete point of having a generic interface called IEntity. :/

Comment: See your points but I guess I lack the knowledge of how to store/retrieve mixed struct types in single array/slice/maps, without interface somehow would have been super nice as well

Comment: you can't store mixed types in a slice/map You would have to use type assertions.

Comment: Yes I guess, I need to read up more on how to work with typed languages in general. In Java for example I would assume that I would be able to use inheritance to solve this, only passing in instances that inherits from a class called Entity but since there is no inheritance in Go I will have to find another way. I'm probably trying to type it to much, I need another design that uses data structures that is more dynamic.

Thanks for your input so far how ever, I'll experiment some more :)